# Instagram Story Api on Android

Tags: android, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

Reading the overview on [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview), it seems like you can only fetch stories of any users only if they have a business account. Here what it states

> This use case is meant for apps that allow business profiles to log in and access their own content; for example, an app that allows businesses to print their own pictures. Apps that fall into this use case must use the basic permission.

So before I request a basic permission on their [New Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview) , I wanted to be sure that fetching stories or other contents are not limited to business accounts only.

If that were the case, which Api would I be able to use to fetch stories on Android knowing the [API Endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) does not return it and most of the ends point there are being deprecated.

If it is not possible at the moment, like I saw on other posts before writing this, How are others people able to fetch stories on non-business account due to the fact I keep seeing those stories grab app on Google Play Store. Which Api are they using?

Thank for any help.

Comment: Have you got any reference ?

Comment: Have you got any solution for your question?